# Set a point after Geolocation result

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am having a terrible time doing something that I think should be quite simple. Draw a point on the location returned by geolocation.

I used the Geocoding example as a starting point: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/point-from-geocoder-result/ but it's gone steadily downhill from there!

My example is here: https://output.jsbin.com/nesec, and the bit that matters is:

```js
geolocator.on('geolocate', function (ev) {
  var myloc = [ev.coords.latitude, ev.coords.longitude];
  map.getSource('single-point').setData(myloc);
});
```

Obviously, I have no idea what I'm doing, but copy and paste has always served me well in the past. Alas, this time I've run out of luck!

Answer (score 0):

**I am clearly an idiot**

I mean, I knew that the code above was wrong - that `myloc` needed to be an Object containing my lat/lng array and so on, but it took me way, way, way too long to realise that the fundamental error was the order of my coordinates - the old lng/lat switcheroo!

Happily, this works:

```
geolocator.on('geolocate', function(ev) {
  var myloc = {type:"Point", coordinates:[ev.coords.longitude,ev.coords.latitude]};
  map.getSource('single-point').setData(myloc);
});
```

Enjoy :-)